# set array size on c++ after initialization

Tags: c++, arrays

```
class foo{

private:
    int map[SCENE_WIDTH * SCENE_HEIGHT];

}
```

The problem is I don't know the SCENE WIDTH yet, I would like to do something like:

```
int map[];

void setSize(int s){
 map[5];
}
```

The only way I know to do this is doing int *map and then map = new int[3] but then I would be using dynamic memory and I would have to delete it later. How to do it like the "first method"?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` and `resize()` instead.

Comment: The short version is, you can't. The size of an array must be a compile-time constant. (Gcc and clang have an extension for run-time sized arrays, I don't believe that will work for a class member though). The normal thing to do here is use the Standard Library component [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Then it's worse if I have to go through the vector because I would need an iterator

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez I don't understand your complaint about needing an iterator? `vector` access is much the same as array access, you use `v[index]` or an iterator which behaves basically the same as a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to resize arrays like that in standard C++.

Instead, use a `std::vector`.  For example;

```
#include <vector>

class foo
{
    public:

        foo(std::size_t size = 0) : map(size) {};     //  initialises number of elements in map

        void resize(std::size_t size)
        {
             map.resize(size);
        };

    private:
       std::vector<int> map;
};
```

The contained `vector<int>` will be destroyed implicitly when an object of type `foo` is destructed, and will release all resources it has allocated.

There are containers other than `std::vector` which meet particular needs, but `std::vector` is a good default choice in practice.

Answer (score 1):

`int map[SIZE];` is allocated *on the stack* and the size of this array *must be known at compile-time* and must be mentioned in the declaration of this variable, because otherwise the syntax `map[5];` will be treated as extraction of the sixth value of this array.

All in all, **you can't do it that way**, but you can use `std::vector` for this purpose.

Comment: `int map[SIZE]` will be allocated wherever a `foo` object is allocated, this could be stack, heap, static data area, or anywhere else